# An if else statement error

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

I keep getting errors with an `if then else` statement. I cant see what is causing the error. The compiler keeps telling me to delete the `else`. The error I'm getting is:

> Syntax error on token "else", delete this token   MonsterTwo.java /Java
>   Code/src/oop/ten  line 259    Java Problem

This is the code:

```
public boolean onMySpace(MonsterTwo[] monster, int indexToChk1,int indexToChk2 )
{
    if(   (monster[indexToChk1].xPosition) == (monster[indexToChk2].xPosition)
       && (monster[indexToChk1].yPosition) == (monster[indexToChk2].yPosition));
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, since you evaluate a boolean expression just for returning the result, you can simply return the expression itself (the `if` is superfluous here).

Comment: Thanks guys iv removed the semicolon and its now working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove semicolon `;` from at the end of if statement

```
if((monster[indexToChk1].xPosition)== (monster[indexToChk2].xPosition)&&
        (monster[indexToChk1].yPosition)== (monster[indexToChk2].yPosition));
{
```

semicolon forces `if` to complete statement, then you would have `else` hanging without `if` which is invalid

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra `;` after your if test, so the `return true;` statement is not in the if block, causing a syntax error with the else block below.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error on your if:

```
if((monster[indexToChk1].xPosition)== (monster[indexToChk2].xPosition)&&
        (monster[indexToChk1].yPosition)== (monster[indexToChk2].yPosition));
                                                      HERE -----------------^
```